# titles for markers on map (titles below markers)

Tags: android, performance, google-maps, bitmap, out-of-memory

I need to draw titles for each of my 1000+ markers on map (titles below markers) . 
For titles I use separate not flat markers and create a separate bitmap for an each title; I faced the next 2 problems:

- creating 1000 bitmaps (plain text wrappers) takes several seconds
- creating 1000 bitmaps consumes a lot of memory, and I regularily get
  OutOfMemory

How to properly draw titles for big number of markers?
Looks like I can not use here any kind of cache or clustering algorithm...
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: 1000+ markers?  are you sure?  who would need it?

Comment: actually we need it and we use 2k+ unique markers, we use clustering and it works well, but now we need to add titles for these markers and we have faced big memory and performance problems here

Comment: but you don't want to show all of them on the view, so create only those that have to be visible

Comment: so either create only visible markers or use a custom overlay view where you could draw whatever you want but the UX will not be as smooth as using the markers which are integrated into google maps

Comment: <<So either create only visible markers>> - looks like it's the only possible solution to create and show only 'title markers' that are visible and remove them when they left visible area. Thanks.